# manipulating binaryjs video with node-canvas

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, websocket, binary

Is it possible to live change video stream with canvas-node?
A'm using binaryjs to send binary frames over web socket and I want to change video live in node-canvas.

This is the code a'm using [Webcam Binary.JS Demo](https://github.com/xat/webcam-binaryjs-demo)
and this is the library that I want to use to change video with canvas [node-canvas](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas)

Is that possible? If that is not possible what is the best solution to combine multiple video streams (with nodejs) to one video?